# Ubuntu Docker image with minimal mono runtime in order to run F# app

Tags: docker, f#, mono

I need to build a "slim" docker image which only contains the mono runtime in order to execute a pre-compiled F# app. In other words, I want to create the leanest possible image for executing mono apps, without any of the additional stuff for compiling/building apps. I am using Ubuntu:16.04 as a my base image (which weighs at around 47MB).

If I try to install mono on top of that image (using apt-get install mono-devel), then the image grows to whopping 500MB. This of course happens because the entire mono development tools are installed.

How can I proceed to only create an image containing the mono runtime? Is there a way installing through apt-get the mono runtime?

Comment: show your Dockerfile, by the way do you do, in only one run, the install and the cleanup?

Comment: This image https://hub.docker.com/r/neoeinstein/mono-alpine/ weighs only 5 MB you can also use the original image https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-mono/

Comment: @user2915097 Yes that was what I was going to do but then I saw that a "glib hack" is mentioned in the link. Not totally sure what that means in practice but I can't rely on a hack for a production environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm answering the question as it is stated:

> How can I proceed to only create an image containing the mono runtime?

For that, the answer is yes. There is a package for just the runtime called `mono-runtime`. In addition to that, there is an `apt` option to ignore installing recommended packages (usually docs and other stuff that may not be necessary for a runtime) with `--no-install-recommends`. Combining the two, we can get down to around 240 MB on the Ubuntu base:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update && apt install -qy --no-install-recommends mono-runtime libfsharp-core4.3-cil
```

Also mentioned in comments, there are some more minimal images based on Alpine linux that may be of interest such as https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-mono/ (which at the moment is around 200 MB).

Comment: Adding to this a little bit, you can explore the different dists for mono [here](http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/). Check the `Packages` files and you'll see what apt-get will process when you try to install a given package. You can use the Packages manifests as a way to see all the different packages for mono, including the `mono-runtime` and `fsharp` if you were wanting to compile fsharp.

Comment: I neglected to realize that F# may require other dependencies as well. They may be able to get away with installing `libfsharp-core4.3-cil` in addition to the runtime. I've amended my answer to be more complete specific to F#.